# Data points not connecting in joined ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to graph a rather large data set with the following expression:

```
ListPlot[ dbf46t1[All, {"Time (hrs)", "RQ1 []"}], 
          PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

But not all of the data points are connected.  Am I missing an obvious step?

[image]

Comment: If each of these points make up your set, please post. Otherwise this will be impossible to recreate.

Comment: I suspect some non-numeric values interspersed with the numeric ones, which will break the line. See if `ListPlot[ Cases[dbf46t1[All, {"Time (hrs)", "RQ1 []"}], _?NumericQ],  PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]` has the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, Verbeia - I checked for non-numeric values but could not find any.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.  Will be posting the data shortly.